# asp button add through span not firing Click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my front End Code in asp.net form

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   <span id="Message" runat="server"></span>
<span id="myid" runat="server">
</span>
</asp:Content>
```

here is my code behind

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myid.InnerHtml = myid.InnerHtml + "<asp:Button ID=" + dbLayer.AddDoubleQuotes("Button_Update") + " name=" + dbLayer.AddDoubleQuotes("Button_Update") + " runat=" + dbLayer.AddDoubleQuotes("server") + " class=" + dbLayer.AddDoubleQuotes("btn btn-success") + " OnClick=" + dbLayer.AddDoubleQuotes("Button_Update_Click") + " Text=" + dbLayer.AddDoubleQuotes("UpdateButton") + " />"; 
    }

     protected void Button_Update_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          Message.InnerHtml = "This Event Fired Sucessfully ...";
    }
```

i am using web Method for Double Quotes

```
    [WebMethod]
public string AddDoubleQuotes(string value)
{
    return "\"" + value + "\"";
}
```

Not Able to get button click event

your reply helps me lot, i am stuck due to this

Comment: You can't add asp controls to a page as plain text like this because the page has already been parsed and interpreted.  Dynamically add controls using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx.

Comment: @PaulAbbott, care to answer the question properly instead of putting it in the comments?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you ***cannot*** just simply render Server Control as string literal in ASP.Net Web Form.

Dynamically added server controls are a little bit tricky since they are not in control tree. You need to reload them back with same ID inside either ***Page_Init*** or ***Page_Load*** event.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="MessageLabel" />

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = new Button {ID = "Button1"};
    button.Click += Button_Click;
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageLabel.Text = "Button is clicked!";
}
```

***FYI:*** Use ASP.Net Server control as much as possible instead of regular html control with `runat="server"`, unless you absolutely certain that you do not need ViewState and some extra features offered by those server controls.

Answer (score 0):

If EnableViewState is false, you can repopulate placeholder controls with different controls dynamically on a postback. The ids do not matter then.